# What are some of the tricks engine can use to render object that have extremely high polygons efficiently?

Tags: physics, rendering

What are some of the tricks engine can use to render object that have extremely high polygons efficiently? I know one thing we do is render only the parts that the camera points at, but I am wondering if there are many more techniques used other than that one.

Comment: Batch, Batch, Batch. There is also a chance that you are seeing less polygons than you think. There is a lot that can be done with textures, levels of detail, and clever shaders to add detail to something with less polygons. But, if we are only talking about high polygon count, no tricks… [Batch, Batch, Batch](https://www.nvidia.com/docs/IO/8228/BatchBatchBatch.pdf).

Comment: Questions asking for open-ended lists of tips are generally considered too broad for this site. Are you currently experiencing an inefficiency problem when rendering high-poly models? If so, editing your question to describe how your rendering process works now, and where your profiling is showing a bottleneck, would help focus this question on one specific problem that we can help you solve. You might already be using some tips, and others might not apply to your situation, so including detail about your problem helps answers zero-in on what new info would be most helpful.

Answer (score 2):

There are three basic approaches to this problem.

**Render Less**

This includes techniques that allow you to skip rendering polygons that are not visible, while maintaining a high polygon count for those that are visible. It might include backface culling, frustum culling, visibility culling; LOD techniques might also fit here.

**Render More Efficiently**

Batching is the classic technique here, but it might also include scene traversal optimizations, shader optimizations, and other techniques that let you get more work out of available compute resources.

**Fake It!**

This includes techniques that let you take a low polygon representation and make it look like high polygon; normal mapping is one classic such technique, but it may also include tessellation or dynamic geometry creation.

On the whole you won't use one of these techniques in isolation, although batching is the one that is most likely to give you best results across the widest variety of use cases.